# Spring Boot search is not working properly

Tags: mysql, database, spring-boot, backend

Here I want to retrieve Hotels by `hotel name`, but it is only returning the Hotels which have first letter which I have included.

I have search Hotel name as "Sigiriya", but when I type "s" it's resulting Sigiriya. But when I start typing more ("igiriya"), the results were gone.

```
/**
     *
     * @param searchkey
     * @return - List of hotels
     */
    public List<Hotel> searchHotelByName( String searchkey){
        searchkey = searchkey.toLowerCase();
        searchkey = "%" + searchkey + "%";

        return hotelRepository.findAllByHotelNameContentLike( searchkey );
    }
```

Comment: Which database are you using? Please add the tag to your question. What is the hotel name and search term?

Comment: I have added it, mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is even though you are converting the search key to lower case, your database is containing upper case letters. Therefore use `ignore case search`.

```
/**
     *
     * @param searchkey
     * @return - List of hotels
     */
    public List<Hotel> searchHotelByName( String searchkey){
        searchkey = searchkey.toLowerCase();

        return hotelRepository.findAllByHotelNameIgnoreCaseContaining( searchkey );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `contains` [JPA keyword](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#_supported_query_keywords)

```
public List<Hotel> searchHotelByName( String searchkey){
    return hotelRepository.findAllByHotelName IgnoreCaseContaining( searchkey );
}
```

`contains` takes care of `%` etc.